# React-native integrated into existing Android apk is giving crash in Asus Zenphone 5. react-native version used : 0.19

Tags: react-native

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed:
>   "/data/app-lib/com.caratlane.android-1/libreactnativejni.so" has
>   unexpected e_machine: 40 E/AndroidRuntime(31481):        at
>   java.lang.Runtime.load(Runtime.java:333) E/AndroidRuntime(31481):
>   at java.lang.System.load(System.java:512) E/AndroidRuntime(31481):
>   at
>   com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource.loadLibrary(DirectorySoSource.java:63)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(31481):        at
>   com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibraryBySoName(SoLoader.java:209)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(31481):        at
>   com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibrary(SoLoader.java:178)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(31481):        at
>   com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeMap.(NativeMap.java:23)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(31481):        at
>   com.microsoft.codepush.react.CodePushPackage.getCurrentPackageInfo(CodePushPackage.java:72)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(31481):        at
>   com.microsoft.codepush.react.CodePushPackage.getCurrentPackageFolderPath(CodePushPackage.java:91)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(31481):        at
>   com.microsoft.codepush.react.CodePushPackage.getCurrentPackageBundlePath(CodePushPackage.java:101)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(31481):        at
>   com.microsoft.codepush.react.CodePush.getBundleUrl(CodePush.java:140)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(31481):        at
>   com.caratlane.android.Activity.HomePageActivity.onCreate(HomePageActivity.java:93)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(31481):        at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5411)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(31481):        at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(31481):        at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(31481):        at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2396)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(31481):        at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(31481):        at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1293)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(31481):        at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(31481):        at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149) E/AndroidRuntime(31481):
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(31481):        at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(31481):        at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(31481):        at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(31481):        at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(31481):        at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Sorry, your question isn't clear. Kindly tell me what you want?

Comment: @JafferWilson Actually i integreted react-native into our existing Android app. It works fine in usually all the phones but not in ASUS zenphone 5. When I install the split "x86" apk it works fine in ASUS but when I am installing universal apk it gives me crash. Error log are already posted above